# HyperJaxb3 - XSD to JPA on Java 1.8: dependencies

Tags: hibernate, jpa, xsd, schema, hyperjaxb

I am trying to use HyperJaxb3 for generating JPA compatible classes from XSD. Here my questions:

- Is the framework compatible with java 1.8?
- Where can I take a running sample of both maven and ant? It seems that original site has been deprecated and on github there are no clear examples on how to use the library.

So many thanks in advance e thanks for all your availability.
Best,
m

Answer (score 0):

- I did not build it with 1.8 yet but I don't expect any problems with that.
- You can get Maven and Ant samples for 0.6.0 from [releases](https://github.com/highsource/hyperjaxb3/releases/tag/0.6.0). If you need newer version, you'll have to build them on your own at the moment. `mvn clean install` in the root dir and the `mvn clean install` in `samples`. Or `mvn clean install -Pall`.

**Disclaimer:** I'm the author of Hyperjaxb3.

Comment: So many thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it because I am getting crazy with dependencies. I'll have a try and I'll be back to you. Thanks!!! :-)

Comment: I've added an answer with errors I am currently receiving. Thanks again for all your support! ;-)

Comment: Unfortunately I can't share xsds :-( BTW, sorry for posting another question in a question and Lexicon, thanks again for your support and your tool. I'll try to face the problem... thanks....